# Ionic React file upload not working on Android

Tags: android, reactjs, ionic-framework, upload, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload an image from the user's phone to the server.

When running the ionic app in the browser, multiple methods work and successfully upload files to the server.

I have tried all the methods from Axios, fetch, Http and none of them want to work on android.

The server responds with:
`Cannot upload file: Content Type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

The most common answer I have seen is a debate on whether I should specify that the Content-Type should be set to Multi-part FormData or not.
I have tried and it then complains about not finding a boundary for said form-data. If I manually hardcode a boundary, I receive no errors from the server but no files get uploaded either.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you still need to change your `config.xml` to be able to upload images through your phone. I am not sure how to do this for iphone since i have only build android only applications with ionic but for android it is by adding

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: @LarsVonk I do not have any issues accessing the files on the Android device. The problem only lies with the upload of it, unfortunately. I have camera and gallery access